# How to pass variable from json-rpc to python script

Tags: javascript, python, http, variables, json-rpc

I want to be able to pass a variable like I=1199 by json-rpc to addon script in another user.

I have this json-rpc and can activate an specific addon in another user:

```
import requests
import xbmc
import xbmcgui
import xbmcplugin
import xbmcaddon

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}

data = '''{
    "jsonrpc":"2.0",
    "method":"Addons.ExecuteAddon",
    "params": {
        "addonid":"script.activatewindowid",
        "params": {
            "i":"1199"
        }
    },
    "id":1
}'''

response = requests.post('http://192.168.1.200:8080/jsonrpc',
    headers=headers,
    data=data,
    auth=('kodi', '1234'))
```

but I need to pass variable or arguments like i="1199" to work in python script like this:

```
import xbmc
import xbmcgui
import xbmcplugin
import xbmcaddon
　
i = "i"
　
if i == "1199":
    xbmc.executebuiltin('ActivateWindow(9000)')
else:
    xbmc.executebuiltin('ActivateWindow(1199)')
```

Sorry but I am still beginner in json-rpc and python

Thanks for all

Comment: Any Help of that please :-)

Comment: Any solution please?